# Click an UIImage and open an UIImageView in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have an UiImage called "thumbnail" on a view, I want to ask how to open an UiImageView when I click on the UiImage(thumbnail)?

This effect is similar to an user click on a small image on a webpage, then popup a larger image.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Add UITapGestureRecognizer to your UIImageView:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector)];
[thumbnail addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];

thumbnail.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // very important for UIImageView
```

Answer (score 2):

A `UIImage` can't exist "on a view" as it is just a representation of some image data. So you'd have an appropriately sized and shaped `UIButton`, with your thumbnail image as it's image, and link this button's action to the creating and presenting of a new UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rather use a UIButton and set its Background image to your image.  Then you can wire an IBAction from this button to your view controller.