# click any UIImage and open an UIImageView in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I got this solution on this site: [Click an UIImage and open an UIImageView in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556215/click-an-uiimage-and-open-an-uiimageview-in-objective-c)

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector)];
[thumbnail addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];

thumbnail.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // very important for UIImageView
```

This is working very fine for single ImageView, but I am adding more than one (about to 20) to my scrollView then How can I differentiate which ImageView will tapped or selected by user. I tried to set my own @selector(imageClicked), but it only returns tag for last imageView.

I am adding addGestureRecognizer in a loop, as I load 20 static images dynamically in an imageView.

Comment: can you please show the code how you are adding 20 image view,that might help us to find out the solution of this problem

Comment: I am sure the issue lies in your loop.

Comment: @gurooj, yes problem was in loop, Piyush solved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    [img setTag:i];
    img.frame= //set frame accordingly;
    img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [img addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
    [scrollView addSubView:img];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

      switch([imageView tag])
    {
       case 1:
          //do your work
          break;
       .
       .
       .
       .
       case n:

    }
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but how do I identify which image is clicked by user! now please don't say by tag. It can be useful after we jump to that action!

Comment: Are you creating separate instance for each imageView ?

Comment: I running a loop, in which I create an UIImageView instance, add it to a add image, add gesture, add tag, and lastly add that instance to scrollview!

Comment: Are you creating each instance of UIImageView in this way              UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]]; If not then try in this way,it should work now

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
for (UIImageView *thumbnail in imageArray)  {
    [thumbnail addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
[tapRecognizer release];
```

You can get the view from the property "view" of UIGestureRecognizer.
In your selector, for example:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

    //  Now do something with your view
}
```

Comment: Make sure the selector is yourSelector: instead of yourSelector. And the received object should be an UIGestureRecognizer. It should get the selected view from user. Can you also post your updated code?

Comment: - (void) imageClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    UIImageView *imageViewClicked=(UIImageView *) recognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"%d",imageViewClicked.tag);
}
/* only focusing to last image */ @Hanon

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a single tap recognizer to multiple views. Create a new one for every view you want to add a tap recognizer to. Since you are using a tableview just do that in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // usual implementation
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeue ...];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init....];
        // add new gesture recognizer here.
    }

    // setup cell: set the image (just an example)
    cell.imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Instead of using tags like mentioned in the other answers, and just getting the imageview try to work with the underlying model. When handling the tap, find the indexPath to know what model object to access:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

    // assumes the image view is direct subview of the cell
    // change to match your cell structure
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [imageView superview]; 

    // get the index path for the cell clicked
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //  TODO: Use index path to get full image to display
}
```

This way you know the exact row of the image clicked, so you can access your model to get access to the full image to display.

Comment: thanks, but I don't add it in tableview! but this might be helpful in some other apps. :)

Comment: ah, sorry, somehow I read tableview where you wrote scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tag to all images - thumbnail.tag = 100 for example.Then modify your selector to youSelector:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
In selector add switch

```
- (void) yourSelector:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    switch(imageView.tag) {
        case 100: {
        //This code will be handled if tag == 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it wont work! and showing SIGABRT error! - (void) imageClicked:(UIImageView *) imageViewSelected
{
    NSLog(@"%d",imageViewSelected.tag);
}

Comment: i understood, my mistake. You need to use code below, and make sure that your selector looks like @selector(yourSelector:)

Comment: this will also wont work! as I tried to write, sender.view is no longer exist!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to subclass the ImageView & add the gesture recognizer to the subclass.

Now for each image create the ImageView object and add the image to that object.
Set some unique property so that you can identify which object click like the name of the image.